# Unit Testing Magic Methods

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

When it comes to unit-testing implementations of magic methods in PHP, what is the recommended means of invoking those methods?

I see three options available:

- Invoking them explicitly/directly:

  `$object->__get('someValue');`
- Invoking them indirectly (using whatever action is intended to trigger them):

  `$object->someValue; \\ Where __get() is implemented.`
- Invoking them using both methods.

Are there any unit testing veterans that could explain which (if any) would be the obvious choice, and why that might be?

*(This may be dancing close to subjective/debate territory, but I will ask in the hopes that there are some generally accepted principles I should consider when approaching this question.)*

Comment: I'm no expert, but it seems that the first one would lead to better (self) documented tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be testing *observable behavior*.  So, the second one (`$obj->property`) *must* be tested, no question.

As for actually calling the getter directly, that's more of a judgement call.  Once you have said `__get('someProperty')`, in my opinion you've pretty much set in stone that it is a magic property.  Since I try to never change the tests, that complicates things quite a bit if, for some reason, I want that to be a plain old non-magic property.  On the plus side, you can call the getter and get the property the other way as well and ensure they both have the exact same result.